# Erro Doctrine Inflector ao salvar arquivos no banco com tinker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer

O erro acontece ao tentar salvar as atualizações no banco de dados, quando eu dou o comando

**$contato->save();**

ele me retorna o erro:

**PHP Deprecated:  The "Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector::pluralize" method is deprecated and will be dropped in doctrine/inflector 2.0. Please update to the new Inflector API. in C:\Users\gusta\Documents\Laravel\cursoLaravel\vendor\doctrine\inflector\lib\Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector.php on line 261**

Pesquisando encontrei que seria como se o Doctrine estivesse corrompido, e tentei o seguinte comando para solucionar com composer:

**composer require doctrine/inflector**

que atualizaria os arquivos e eu nao teria problema, mas nao foi bem isso, ele me retorna outro erro.

**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]